In tailscale ACLs how can I allow all access except for one particular locked-down machine?
I'm using tailscale. I'd like to set up a public-facing server which only allows incoming connections to port 9100, but is otherwise disconnected from the tailnet (no outgoing connections). I see how to set up acls, but it's not clear to me if putting a specific rule for that machine first will work. Something like this?
"acls": [
      // Lock down one server
      {
      "action": "accept",
      "src": ["*"],
      "dst": ["website-docker-host-1:9100"]   // Only this port on this host
      },
      // General rule letting machines talk to each other (XXX: should exclude website-docker-host-1)
      {
      "action": "accept",
      "src": ["*"],
      "dst": ["*:*"],
      },
  ],

I wish there were an "all-except-this-host" acl; maybe I'm missing it?
